# “Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup” error in command

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I have a command:

```
  \newcommand{\lineunderscore}{\uline{\hspace*{\fill}}}
```

But when i try to use this command, i keep getting errors

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\lineunderscore}{\uline{\hspace*{\fill}}}


test\lineunderscore\\test

\end{document}
```

Like `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`, what is my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't put complicated macros inside `\uline` I think you wanted

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\lineunderscore}{\uline{\hfill}}


test\lineunderscore\\test

\end{document}
```

although I would probably use

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


test\hrulefill\\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! +1. Out of curiosity, *why* do complicated macros like `\hspace` not work? (And what makes a macro complicated?)

Comment: @chsk a macro is "complicated" in this context if it fails.  Actually the real complication is `\ulem` which is a massively complicated macro trying to do underlining while still allowing normal line breaking and inter-word space stretching, it needs to be able to deconstruct its argument, and rebuild something equivalent but underlined.  so putting in anything more than simple letters might work, but generally wit will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (And that's a rather philosophical definition. I like it.)